# Add file location (figure) in windows ST3

Tags: sublime-text

I have been using Sublime Text 3 with Latexing to produce my documents.

However, I need to add lots of screenshots in my document. 
I am on windows and one can think how difficult it can be to get absolute paths right.

Any Latexing or ST3 support in this regard to ease insertion of absolute paths would be very  helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use absolute paths? Might be easier with relative paths. The following command `\graphicspath{dir-list}` might also help you with your absolute paths (from `graphicx` package)

Comment: I need to definitely add an absolute path, the pngs are somewhere else and the doc is somewhere else. Not sure if \graphicspath{dir-list} could be useful.

Comment: If you have all graphics at different directories `\graphicspath` won't help, but this is quite uncommon. If you would like to compile again you need to place all the images at the right folders. It might be a good idea to copy them all in a subfolder. (but probably this won't fit to your application)

Comment: I do have all my graphics at one location and I have successfully tried `\graphicspath`, which is good but was just one part. However I want some more help from ST3: that it parses all the folders in the project and presents a list and I am able to include file's path in few clicks. I am sure it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package latexing (http://www.latexing.com/) and `\graphicspath{dir-list}` solved the problem.

Install the Latexing plugin and configure it so that its working according to your needs.

Keep the `screenshots` folder in the same directory as the `.tex` file.

In the header of the document add: `\graphicspath{{Z:/screenshots/}, {Y:/path/to/dir/having/the/tex/file}}`

To include a file path in the document: press `ctrl+shift+l`, `ctrl+shift+l`. 
[image]

You will be presented with a few options, select: "Fill Include Graphics Anywhere"; just start typing the file name, and click the one you've got to insert:

[image]

The path (`screenshots/backAnno/Screenshot-Done-1.png`) will be inserted at the cursor, and you are done now!